# How to listen real time database from Firebase in Django Admin

Tags: django, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I have a Flutter project that receives push notifications from a Django Panel. Within the Flutter project, I have a function that sends push notifications to specific users. Now, I want to extend this functionality to send notifications to my Django Admin and display them as desktop notifications.

I have explored Firebase's documentation but couldn't find a way to listen to the Real-Time Database from my Django Panel. Is it possible to achieve this integration between Flutter, Firebase, and Django? If so, what approaches or alternatives should I consider?

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Reviewed the Firebase documentation for any relevant information.
- Searched online for similar use cases but couldn't find a suitable solution.

In my Django Panel, I've used the following code to listen to notification changes:

```py
cred = credentials.Certificate('my-credentials')
firebase_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL': 'my-project-firebase-link'
})

notification_ref = db.reference('notifications')

def listen_to_notification_changes(event):
    notification_data = list(event.data.values())
    latest_notification = notification_data[-1]
    if isinstance(latest_notification, dict):  
        title = latest_notification.get("title", "")
        subtitle = latest_notification.get("subtitle", "")
    else:
        title = ""  
        subtitle = ""  

    notification.notify(
        title=title,
        message=subtitle,    
    )

notification_ref.listen(listen_to_notification_changes)
```

However, this code executes every time the app is launched, showing the last notification despite of it is was already shown.
Moreover, this code ask for all the notifications from the database and this is not optimal because I only want the last one.
I'm also aware that Flutter provides a more efficient way to achieve the same functionality using the **FirebaseMessaging.onMessage listener**.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to optimize this integration and only retrieve the latest notification from the Real-Time Database. Additionally, if there are alternative approaches I should consider, please let me know.

Comment: This is really broad, and it's unlikely somebody will write a tutorial as an answer. If I search, I find some articles like this one on [Integrating Firebase with Django](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/integrating-firebase-database-in-django/) and [How to Get Started with Firebase Using Python](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-started-with-firebase-using-python/). If you saw those already and tried it, it's probably easier to help if you edit your question to [show what you tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and where you got stuck.

Comment: Frank, I made an edit. I hope it helps you to understand my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation [Realtime listeners for the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-event-types) are only available in the Admin SDKs for Node.js and Java, not in the Admin SDK for Python.

But you can still reduce the amount of data you retrieve by [using a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-queries), which is available in the SDK for Python too. A query for Firebase Realtime Database consists of a few steps:

1. You first [order the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#python_2) on either the key, the value, or the value of a child property.
2. You then [select a range](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#range-queries) of the values you order on.
3. You then optionally [limit the number of results you get back](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#limit-queries).

So you could for example order your data on the keys or some timestamp value in there, and only request the latest value.

Comment: Thank you Frank, that worked, but now the issue I'm currently facing is that the function is being executed twice every time a new notification is added to Firebase.